# Why does youtube-dl sometimes fail with "ERROR: No video formats found"?

Tags: 20.04, downloads, youtube, youtube-dl

Youtube-dl sometimes works, sometimes doesn't work:

```
youtube-dl https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=62uM1trEf6M
[youtube] 62uM1trEf6M: Downloading webpage
ERROR: No video formats found; please report this issue on https://yt-dl.org/bu
```

My Ubuntu version is 20.04. 5 min ago, I downloaded videos without any problems.

Can someone elaborate on this?

Comment: Can you add a verbose output and version when that happens? It's working for me.

Comment: update it, this program changes almost daily as yooboob try continuously to circumvent it.

Comment: use youtube-dl from git https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl but remove other versions before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got the following result in Ubuntu 20.04.

```
$ youtube-dl -F https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=62uM1trEf6M
[youtube] 62uM1trEf6M: Downloading webpage
ERROR: No video formats found; please report this issue on https://yt-dl.org/bug.   
Make sure you are using the latest version; see https://yt-dl.org/update on how   
to update. Be sure to call youtube-dl with the --verbose flag and include its  
complete output.
```

The results of `snap run youtube-dl -F https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=62uM1trEf6M` were successful, which indicates that the youtube-dl apt package which is packaged as a .deb package in 20.04 is not up-to-date enough to download this video. Please install the latest stable youtube-dl snap package:

```
sudo snap install youtube-dl
```

After installing it you will have two youtube-dl packages installed, and you can invoke the snap package using `snap run youtube-dl` instead of `youtube-dl`

Comment: `youtube-dl` is not a snap package. What are you talking about?

Comment: @Tem326 What are the results of the command: `snap info youtube-dl`? This command should show  a description of the youtube-dl snap package. The stable version of  the youtube-dl snap package was last updated 26 days ago.

Comment: snap run youtube-dl https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4r8XfE_VNb0
error: cannot find current revision for snap youtube-dl: readlink /snap/youtube-dl/current: no such file or directory

Comment: @RET `snap run youtube-dl youtube.com/watch?v=4r8XfE_VNb0` works on my computer.

Comment: @karel error: no snap found for "youtube-dl"

Comment: @Tem326 Results of `snap info youtube-dl` are `name:      youtube-dl   summary:   Download videos from youtube.com or other video platforms`